# Wait for foreground process to emit string, then send to background

Tags: bash, shell-script, process

With a `bash` script I'm trying to start a process, wait for it to write a specific string to `stdout` (i.e. `'Server Initialized'`), and then send it to the background and continue with the script. Even better if once `'Server Initialized'` is printed the process output is ignored (redirected to `/dev/null`?)

As a hack right now I'm waiting 10 seconds and assuming the server has started.

```
( ./long_running_process ) > /dev/null 2>&1 &
# sleep 10
echo 'I run after long_running_process prints "Server Initialized"
```

Bonus points if, after some timeout, the search string hasn't appeared then exit with an error status code.

Comment: Are you developing the server? Because a fork once it is initialized would be much easier...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea is to run the server in the background and then grep its output as long as the expected string has appeared `'Something 3'` (`'Server Initialized'` in your case)

```
#!/bin/bash

main()  
{
    output=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}$(basename $0).XXX")
    server &> $output &
    server_pid=$!
    echo "Server pid: $server_pid"
    echo "Output: $output"
    echo "Wait:"
    until grep -q -i 'Something 3' $output
    do       
      if ! ps $server_pid > /dev/null 
      then
        echo "The server died" >&2
        exit 1
      fi
      echo -n "."
      sleep 1
    done
    echo 
    echo "Server is running!" 
}

server() 
{       
    i=0
    while true; do
      let i++
      echo "Something $i"  
      sleep 1
    done
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: This is great, thanks; I think after `basename` it should say `$0` not just `0`, though.